# DRIVER local position bug when rotating

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, transforms, drivers

[image]I've made a driver that "animates" a bone by moving a controller on the local x-axis, but when I rotate the controller, Blender doesn't seem to take the fact that it rotated into consideration.
Is there a way so solve this?

To show you what I mean go check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eHDEYCCYmw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Could you also provide an image of the driver setup?

Comment: I think you have to copy the driver for the X axis, to also the Y axis, or else it will only effect the X axis(because that is the only axis with drivers).

Comment: batfinger i just added one and WhovianBron3 i'm not sure to understand what your trying to say, can you explain ?